# Why Template of control is null at startup?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I am trying to get `Thumb` of `Slider`.

```
_thumb = ((Track)AssociatedObject.Template.FindName("PART_Track", AssociatedObject))?.Thumb;
```

This throws NRE because `Template` is null. Why `Template` is null during application startup? and how can I fix that?

I tried code below

```
AssociatedObject.ApplyTemplate(); // no effect. returns false.
var template = AssociatedObject.Template; // returns null.
```

Even though I apply template its still null.

Previously I was overriding the slider `OnApplyTemplate` and Template was not null.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    // works fine.
    _thumb = ((Track)this.Template.FindName("PART_Track", this))?.Thumb;
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
}
```

But now I am trying to create Behavior for Slider rather than creating a subclass so I cant override. Any Idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I could use `Loaded` event and get Thumb there.

```
AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObjectOnLoaded;

private void AssociatedObjectOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    _thumb = ((Track)AssociatedObject.Template.FindName("PART_Track", AssociatedObject))?.Thumb;
}
```